# Handle android server communication after errors

Tags: java, android, android-service, communication

My android app is using a http connection to send data to a server. If the server received the data the app marks the data as successfully transmitted in its own database.

Sometimes external problems may occur, so that the transmission cannot be completed. The app should try sending the data again later.

What is a good possibility to make sure, that the data reaches the server? I only can think of a service, which checks periodically for not transmitted data, but I don't like this approach.

Comment: Why don't you like it?

Comment: Make the server such that it will allow multiple tries to upload the data. Also let server send a special "acknowledgement" as response (md5 hash of data would be a good candidate). Then you can keep retrying on items whose acknowledgements are not yet received from server.

Comment: @Fildor: The service should check two things periodically which can affect the performance: are there pending messages and is the device online. I have now Idea how big the interval should be (maybe even dynamically changing?). Maybe this approach is better than I think, but I don't know how to organize it.

Comment: @S.D. I only transmit short json strings. The server is giving a feedback when the data was transmitted successfully, but how should this "retrying" look like?

Comment: Retrying looks like the first try. - **IF** it is legitimate to send the same data twice such that the second time it won't change server's sate. As soon as the data has been confirmed, delete it from the list of things to be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres some psuedo code..

1.Create a AcknowledgementManager which waits for acknowledgement of each request.

2.The acknowledgement manager posts a runnable which will run after TIME_OUT interval.

```
    public void startListeningForTimeOut(CallContext callContext) {
    TimeOutRunnable timeOutRunnable = new TimeOutRunnable(callContext);
    mMapRunnables.put(callContext, timeOutRunnable);
    mHandler.postDelayed(timeOutRunnable, TIMEOUT_DURATION);
    Slog.d(TAG,
            "started listening for timeout for token: " + callContext + " at: "
                    + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

3.1 If the AcknowledgementManager receives acknowledgement for the data it cancels the runnable for that data and make necessary updates in database.

```
    public void stopListeningForTimeOut(CallContext callContext) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mMapRunnables.get(callContext));
    mMapRunnables.remove(callContext);
    Slog.d(TAG,
            "stopped listening for timeout for token: " + callContext + " at: "
                    + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

3.2 If the acknowledgement is not received the runnable raises a "timeout" to the AcknowledgementManager.The AcknowledgementManager retries sending data.

```
  public class TimeOutRunnable implements Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "TimeOutThread rupesh";

    CallContext mToken;

    // String mCallback;

    public TimeOutRunnable(CallContext callContext) {
        mToken = callContext;
        // mCallback = callbackTBD;
        // FIXME send proper callback class
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Slog.d(TAG, "timeout occured for data id: " + mToken + " at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        mToken.onTimeOutOccurred();
    }

}
```

Please note:

1.Before syncing the data please make the entry of data in db so that the data does not get lost between app restart.

2.Before you start the syncing process query the db to get the data which is not being transmitted.Based on the data size,make sure you keep the data to be transmitted in memory to avoid hitting the db everytime.

3.Once you get acknowledgement for a data item,make necessary changes for that entry in db.

4.You can also have 'retry' flag in db so that you keep track of no of retries.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This is one way to accomplish the periodical approach? But I see the problem: If the device shuts down or the user terminates the app, the information is lost, which message was not transmitted to the server. I have a sqlite database for every message with an extra field, if this message was transmitted successfully. So I can check the database (periodically) for not transmitted messages. Do you see any advantages using your approach?

Comment: @jasdefer Store data locally on disk/Database, and only then sync it, Don't sync data from RAM, it will be lost on shut down.